# How to call func2 inside func1 while func1 keeps running and returning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

Code example:

```py
def func2(paraI):
    time.sleep(10)
    print('awaked, i=%d'%paraI)

def func1():
    i = 5
    # func2 will use parameter inside func1
    # but func1 doesn't depend on func2
    # so func2 is expected to run another thread
    # and func1 will keep running (return)
    func2(i)
    return i

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(func1())
```

I would like the output `5` immediately, and after 10s `awaked, i=5` is printed, rather than being blocked for 10s then `awaked, i=5 5`.

How can I achieve this in Python3? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module in Python:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = func2, args = (i, ))
thread.start()
```

Try this:

```
import threading
import time

def func2(paraI):
    time.sleep(10)
    print('awaked, i = %d' % paraI)

def func1():
    i = 5
    # func2 will use parameter inside func1
    # but func1 doesn't depend on func2
    # so func2 is expected to run another thread
    # and func1 will keep running (return)
    print("Starting the Thread")
    thread = threading.Thread(target = func2, args = (i,))
    thread.start()
    return i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Func1 returned", func1())
```

Output:

```
Starting the Thread
Func1 returned 5
```

And after `10` seconds,...

```
awaked, i = 5
```